# Как исправить мой слайдер?

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал учить javascript. Есть такой код:

```js
let pos = 0;
let track = document.querySelector('.slider-track');
let translatePercent = 33.33;

document.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 600) {
    translatePercent = 33.33;
  } else {
    translatePercent = 100;
  }

  if (pos < document.querySelectorAll('.slide').length - 1) {
    pos++;
  }
  track.style.transform = 'translateX(' + pos * translatePercent * (-1) + '%)'
}

document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
  if (pos > 0) {
    pos--;
  }
  track.style.transform = 'translateX(' + pos * translatePercent * (-1) + '%)';
}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-track {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s;
}

.slide {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide-1 {
  background: #240;
}

.slide-2 {
  background: #840;
}

.slide-3 {
  background: #240;
}

.slide-4 {
  background: #d40;
}

.slide-5 {
  background: #75e;
}

.slide-6 {
  background: #25e;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .slide {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-track">
    <div class="slide slide-1">1</div>
    <div class="slide slide-2">2</div>
    <div class="slide slide-3">3</div>
    <div class="slide slide-4">4</div>
    <div class="slide slide-5">5</div>
    <div class="slide slide-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="prev">Обратно</button>
<button class="next">Туда</button>
```

У меня проблема в том, что слайдер не идет каруселью, в нём 6 елементов, но он показывает ещё 2 которых нету, не могу придумать как поставить кнопки сбоку, проблема с адаптивом почему-то и нету цикличности. Пробовал рыться, да к моему говно-коду что-то ничего не лезет, что можете посоветовать?
Вот код на codepen - https://codepen.io/Cherneshenko/pen/RwZadYY

Comment: Оформите код в сниппет, который можно запустить на сайте.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Cherneshenko/pen/RwZadYY - Вот на кодепен

Comment: Почему не выложили на сайте? Вот вам [пример](https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/) как делать карусели.